What does "Bob's your uncle" mean
I'm pretty curious about the phrase "Bob's your uncle". What does it mean and why?
I've registered for English courses but I'm too shy to ask my teacher about this.

It's true that Bob's your uncle is primarily a British expression. But it's not exactly unknown in the US, and it's on Wikipedia and in some dictionaries (including that link to US-centric Merriam-Webster).

A question abut the etymology of the idiom might be On Topic on English Language and Usage, but imho neither the etymology nor the meaning are On Topic here on a learners site.

@FumbleFingers - I had a colleague who had the irritating habit, when explaining how easy a process was, of combining two or three of these sayings - bish bash bosh, Bob's your uncle, job's a good 'un.

@MichaelHarvey: I've always been a great fan of bish bash bosh, even though I seem to be incapable of incorporating it into my productive vocabulary. What I especially like is you nearly always get exactly those three vowels in that order, which reinforces my long-held opinion that slang, colloquialisms (and especially swear-words) tend to be replicated even more precisely than general-purpose or "formal" language. People care much more about falling into line with their highly-localized "idiolectic peer group" than with "society" at large.

@FumbleFingers You get two of those vowels in that order in flim-flam, mish-mash, ping_pong, and ding-dong. Is there a pattern? But la jolie cloche (Trenet)/les matines (Frere Jacques) fait ding-dang-dong.

@MichaelHarvey: I often wish John Lawler was still with us. I'd like to have asked him whether (a) there's a pattern, and (b) if so, is it peculiar to English, or to Germanic and/or Romance roots, OR common to most/all languages? And I bet he'd have known.

@FumbleFingers - Indeed! I also remember fee-fi-fo-fum which fits the aeiou vowel order too.

@MichaelHarvey: Not to mention Old MacDonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O. But surely it can only be coincidence that the sequence of vowels in our ABC happens to be reflected in many such "nonsense" sounds? I mean coincidence on the ABC side,, not the sounds themselves, which maybe do have this tendency for a reason. Maybe this is one for SE Linguistics?

@FumbleFingers - until I was aged 25 I thought 'Eieio' was how you spelled 'farm'.

Me, I had no idea how to write E-I-E-I-O there, so I just googled Old MacDonald farm.

OP's query:

I'm pretty curious about some phrase. That's "Bob's your uncle". What does it mean and why?

"Bob's your uncle" is a British slang phrase meaning something is easy, uncomplicated, or taken care of. It's often used to conclude instructions or imply a goal is easily attainable. This phrase originated from British Prime Minister Lord Salisbury's 1887 appointment of his nephew, Arthur Balfour, as Irish Secretary, which was seen as unfair favoritism. Today, "Bob's your uncle" signifies that everything is set, and you've got it made.

Ref. math.fsu.edu.
Bob's your uncle" means that everything is taken care of for you—you're all set, you've got it made. The expression apparently dates back to 1887 when the original "Uncle Bob"—British Prime Minister Lord Salisbury—made his nephew (Arthur Balfour) Irish Secretary in a move that reeked of nepotism.
https://www.math.fsu.edu/~mesterto/bobisyouruncle.html#:~:text=%22Bob's%20your%20uncle%22%20means%20that,move%20that%20reeked%20of%20nepotism.


Downvoted for the same reason as comments under @Pete's answer. It's simply not credible that the origin was from a political move in 1887, but with no recorded instances until it first appeared in print in Partridge's slang dictionary in 1937. And your semantic link is totally unconvincing to me anyway.

@FumbleFingers All links are showing the same result. Link 3 gave Oxford dictionary reference:

https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/why-do-we-say-bobs-your-uncle
https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/why-do-we-say-bobs-your-uncle
https://www.suzannearnold.com/blog/l11iyhht9m5ruuhzf82nejo6qcjscq


I've just checked all 3 links in my comment under the question, and they all look fine to me (1=my Ngram chart, 2=Wikipedia, 3=M-W dictionary). My comments under Pete's answer don't include links, but I cut&pasted Partridge's dismissal in its entirety (I can't access the Partridge source directly, so I don't even know if he proposed some alternative etymology, but I doubt it). The full OED is paywalled anyway, but they certainly don't lend credence to the Balfour etymology. Nor does their definition 3. 1937– Slang phr. Bob's (bob's) your uncle: everything is all right support it at all.

(Before being edited, this question looked for all the world like spam anyway, so it's no biggie.)

This is quite easy to look up online. Its derivation is not rude, but refers to nepotism. "Bob" is short for Robert, who was in an influential position and favoured friends and relatives with jobs.

Even Wikipedia admits that the supposed etymology (PM Gascoyne-Cecil appointing nephew Arthur Balfour to high office in 1887) is "uncertain". Partridge contemptuously dismisses it with The bob’s your uncle entry uncritically tells the Arthur Balfour nepotism story with the cop-out introduction “most commentators offer ...”. Readers don’t want to know what most commentators say; they want to learn what the editors have concluded on the basis of their own research. And the full OED doesn't even bother to mention that "folk etymology" for a term first recorded in 1937 (by Partridge! :)

...so far as I'm concerned, it's not important that the etymology is rubbish. This answer is misleading because the actual current use of the idiom definitely has nothing to do with nepotism (and almost certainly never did, but that's irrelevant).
